# Proving Independence Intuitively

Tags: probability-theory, independence

The setup is: $Z \sim N(0,1), X = |Z|, Y=\mathrm{sgn}(Z)$

And the question is whether $X\bot Y$

Now, unless I am missing something, this intuitively has to be true - no information about the magnitude of $Z$ tells me the sign and vice versa.

Now, I can prove this via the traditional methods of proving independence of random variables. But since this problem seems to be this obvious, I wonder whether a proof could be done along the lines of this intuition.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, unless I am missing something, this intuitively has to be true - no information about the magnitude of $Z$ tells me the sign and vice versa.

Yes indeed, the standard normal distribution is *symmetrical about zero* and this implies that.   That is sufficient.

It's sufficient because two random variables are defined as being independently distributed if the realisation of one does not influence the probability distribution of the other.   You've established that this indeed happens almost everywhere, therefore these two random variables are almost surely independent.

---

( Well, actually there is just one *point* where the sign does convey perfect information about the magnitude and vice versa.   However, $X,Y$ are *almost surely* independent. )

---

Symbolically $\forall x{\in}\Bbb R^+\, \forall y{\in}\{-1,1\} \big( f_Z(xy) = f_X(x)\,p_Y(y)\big)$ since: $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}f_Z(x)+f_Z(-x) & : x\in \Bbb R^+ \\ f_Z(0) & : x=0 \\ 0 & : \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\text{ and }p_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \tfrac 1 2 & : y={-}1\vee y={+}1 \\ 0\text{ a.s.} & : y=0 \\ 0 & : \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: But *why* is it sufficient? Good points about $a.s$, thanks, it's good to never forget that, my brain just automatically disregards anything of measure zero.

Comment: Its sufficient because two random variables are defined as being independently distributed if the realisation of one does not influence the probability distribution of the other. You've established that this happens almost everywhere, therefore these two random variables are independent.

Comment: I guess what I'd like to see is some mathematical notation, as the problem is precisely the perceived tenuous link between *english words* (no matter how convinced I am of their validity) and *mathematical notation* that I know how to work with and can identify as a sufficient proof

Comment: Thanks, I agree with the equality, but I am still not there, how does this prove that the distributions are independent?

Comment: What does independent almost surely mean?

Comment: What is says: they are independent almost everywhere and the exception having almost zero measure probability.

Comment: What? Two random variables are independent if $P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$ for all $A,B$. How does 'almost surely' enter here?